# Trouble with Div Overflows

Tags: css, wordpress, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm in a bit of an overflow conundrum right now.

I have a layout that is supposed to have a white container with rounded corners. The footer (which is at the bottom of the container, and inside of it) is a shade of grey. I used 'overflow-x:hidden' to make sure the bottom corners of the footer div were rounded with the container.

The problem is, when I hide the overflow, the css ribbon (that I'm using in the header) folds are hidden.

I'm trying to figure out a way to rearrange the DIVs to achieve a layout that has the rounded corners and the ribbon at the top, but am having trouble.

I am using WordPress along with Bootstrap to code my layout. Here's my code as it stands (without the hidden overflow).

CSS:

```
.container {
  clear: both;
  margin: 20px auto;
  width: 940px;
  background: #fff;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  -khtml-border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  -khtml-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  position: relative;
  z-index: 90; /* the stack order: displayed under ribbon rectangle (100) */
/*   overflow-x: hidden; */
  *zoom: 1;
}

/* Ribbon 
-------------------------------------------------*/

.rectangle {
    background: #80D4F6;
    height: 50px;
    width: 970px;
    position: relative;
    left:-15px;
    top: 30px;
    float: left;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.35);
    -khtml-box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.35);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.35);
    z-index: 100; /* the stack order: foreground */
    margin: -30px 0px 0px;
}

.rectangle h2 {
    font-size: 40px;
    font-family: 'Grand Hotel', cursive, Georgia, helvatica;
    color: #fff;
    padding-top: 6px;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    text-align: center;
}

.rectangle h2 a{
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

.triangle-l {
    border-color: transparent #7d90a3 transparent transparent;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:15px;
    height:0px;
    width:0px;
    position: relative;
    left: -30px;
    top: 35px;
    z-index: -1; /* displayed under bubble */
}

.triangle-r {
    border-color: transparent transparent transparent #7d90a3;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:15px;
    height:0px;
    width:0px;
    position: relative;
    left: 940px;
    top: 5px;
    z-index: -1; /* displayed under bubble */
}

/* Footer
-------------------------------------------------*/

.site-footer{
    padding-top: 10px;
    background: #f6f6f6;
}
```

And here is how the HTML is formatted:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span12">
            NAV
            <div class="rectangle"><h2>SITE TITLE</h2></div>
            <div class="triangle-l"></div> <!-- Left triangle -->
            <div class="triangle-r"></div> <!-- Right triangle -->
            SLIDESHOW
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span8">
            CONTENT
        </div>
        <div class="span4">
            SIDEBAR
        </div>
    </div>
    <footer class="site-footer" role="contentinfo">
        <div class="row">
            FOOTER
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The issue can be seen [here](http://www.noellesnotes.com)(the footer's corners aren't rounded because I "unhid" the overflow to allow the ribbon folds to show).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this `css` in you `style.css` file

```
.site-footer {
border-radius:0 0 10px 10px;
-webkit-border-radius:0 0 10px 10px;
-moz-border-radius:0 0 10px 10px;
}
```

Comment: i was just about to type this answer haha just make both divs have border radius but make the footer only have bottom border radius